# How to change whatsapp wallapaper through my app programatically?

Tags: android

Hello friends there's a option in whatsapp through which we can change the background wallpaper of whatsapp chat. I am making a project in which i am giving so many wallpapers and i want to set the wallpaper from my wallpaper list

I used this code but the code is not working

```
Intent shareIntent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("image/*");
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.mypackagename/"+R.drawable.image);
shareI
ntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share via"));Intent = new
```

Comment: your mediaplayer issue solved?

Comment: yes and thanks for paying attention

Answer (score 1):

There are two thing you have to define for allow other application to call your application or request..

- Define `<intent-filter>` in Mainfest.xml
- Check for `Intent` at `onCreate` method..
- `Intent` to host activity with Activity RESULT

If you want to share your image/text to other application on other call there are two way..

1. Share image your with host application on call

For this you have to use `android.intent.action.SEND` filter

2. Answer to host application for image request

For this you have to use `android.intent.action.PICK` filter

Manifest.xml

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/image1"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            <!-- share your image with host application -->
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>

            <!-- answer to host application for image request -->
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:mimeType="image/*"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

OnCreate in `MainActivity`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // get intent from host activity
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if(!intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.MAIN")){

        // check about request 
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PICK")) {

        // return to activity with result OK and image selected image   
        Intent result = new Intent("com.example.RESULT_ACTION", Uri.parse("content://result_uri"));
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, result);
        finish();        
        }
    }
}
```